# Nested classes — can't understand their functionality

Tags: python, class, nested

I'm learning about classes in Python, particularly about nested classes.

I'm trying to execute the below code and I get an error: `int object is not callable`, but
I don't understand why!

All I want is to create an object that identify `Man`, and he has hands, and the hands have their own size, length, etc...

I want to be able to set the hand size and get its value in the most elegant and easy way as possible and nothing work for me... I tried the below code and I really thought it would work but it didn't and now I know that "I Don't know" what to do for real.

```
class Man:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = self.Hand_Object()  # Here we reference an Object called 
                                        # "hand" to the subvlass "Hand_Object".
    def length(self , length):
        self.length = length

    def handsize(self, size=None):  # This "handsize()" function will call the
                                    # subclass function "length()" out from the
                                    # Hand_Object vlass when it will be issued
                                    # in the program.
        if size==None:
            return = self.hand.length()
        else:
            self.hand.length(size)  # The "length()" function of the "Hand_Object"
                                    # class requires a variable, so when we call
                                    # that function we need to add a variable to it.

    class Hand_Object:
        def length(self, length=None):
            if length == None:
                return self.length
            else:
                self.length = length

        def fingers(self, fingers):
            self.fingers = fingers

myman = Man('shlomi')
myman.handsize(6)
print(myman.handsize())    # Here I get the error.
```

Comment: what is `return = self.hand.length()` supposed to be doing? It doesn't do anything, and besides, you shouldn't use the word `return` unless you're actually returning something.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: it should start the Hand_Object.length() function, and retunr the returned value from that function

Comment: @nitayp1 but that's not how returning works, and you even have other correct returns in your code. It should be `return self.hand.length()`, just like all your other `return`s. However that's not the issue; I posted an answer with the actual problem that's causing your error, though.

Comment: Yes, I can see there are 3 different ways to access the "hand.length" variable

Comment: BTW, in my opinion there is no reason why those classes should be nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the line `self.length = length` in `Hand_Object`. You're overwriting the function `length` with an integer. You should call the function and the variable something different.

Comment: Thanks you very much , I really need to be more carefull with the names and variables , its a good point for me to learn this stuff